# user data accessible through javascript in browser

Tags: web-browser, javascript

There are websites which display user information, such as browser version and operating system

[This](http://www.whatismybrowser.com) website goes even further, and displays some additional information, such as desktop resolution, and also any secondary network interfaces. In my case, it detected my eth1 network interface 192.168.0.6

I have noticed that this information is only available when `javascript` is enabled. I am wondering therefore, what else is accessible through `javascript`. In particular, if `javascript` can access files in users home.

Comment: Your question is kind of general as javascript in a browser can access a number of relevant characteristics of your system (screen resolution, window size, OS version, browser version, browser plug-ins installed, etc...).  It cannot however access arbitrary files on your computer or your home network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a moving target, as there is a cat-and-mouse game as attackers discover new techniques and browsers implement new defences. In general, JavaScript:

- **can** access config information about your browser and plugins. The site you linked seems to be a good summary of the current techniques.
- **cannot** access your local files, at least, unless you explicitly drag and drop a file (or use a file upload field). Nor can it access your address book.
- **can only** access cookies (and HTML 5 local storage) from its own domain, not others.
- **can sometimes** see your web history, using [CSS history sniffing](http://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/). This leak is largely fixed in newer browsers, but some subtle issues remain.
- **can** load resources (e.g. images) from other sites. It can't access the content (unless it's an explicitly allowed cross-domain request).
- **cannot** access JSON data from other sites. This used to be possible using [JSON Hijacking](http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2011/05/30/json-hijacking/) but modern browsers have fixed this.
- **can** tell how long a resource takes to load. This can be abused to tell if a user is logged in to a particular site, and even if they have any messages that match a particular search string.
- **can** exploit vulnerabilities (e.g. cross-site scripting, cross-site request forgeries) on other web sites, and against the web browser itself.
- **can** perform computations for the site owner, using the client's computer e.g. BitCoin mining.

An interesting related question is what can content like Java, Flash and PDF do? My knowledge runs out here, but I do know that a PDF file can print a document with no user interaction. Quite surprising - a fully patched 2014 browser allows an untrusted website to automatically print!

If you want to know the full story, read [The Browser Security Handbook](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part1).

Comment: That is interesting. But how can you explain then, that the website can see my secondary network interface?

Comment: @MartinVegter - The site uses WebRTC to get that information; https://www.whatismybrowser.com/what-is-my-local-ip-address I would class this as example of my first point "config information".

Answer (score 0):

One more point is the [GeoLocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation), which can be used to determine your coordinates.

If it is available and the user agrees, you can do

> ```
> navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
>   do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
> });
> ```